# Counting the number of equivalence classes with rows

Tags: logic, order-theory

**The problem**

Let $X$ be a set. We define an equivalence relation ~ on $X^{\mathbb{N}}$:

$(a_n)_n$ ~ $(b_n)_n \iff \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N},  \forall n \geq n_0 : a_n = b_n$ for $(a_n)_n, (b_n)_n \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Show that $|X^{\mathbb{N}}/$~$| = 2^k $ if $ |X| = 2^k$ with $k\geq |\mathbb{N}|$

**My attempt**

I tried to construct an injection from the equivalence classes to $X$, by mapping the "last element" of the rows from each equivalence class to $X$ but I'm pretty sure this isn't correct. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $|X^{\mathbb N} / \sim | \le |X|^{\mathbb N}$. And we actually have that equality holds: By assigning each $x \in X$ to the equivalence class of the function $c_{x} \colon \mathbb N \to \{x \}$, we obtain that $|X| \le |X^{\mathbb N} / \sim |$. Now prove that, under the given assumptions, $|X| = |X|^{\mathbb N}$ and you're done.

Comment: The part where we assign each $x \in X$ to an equivalence class of that particular function, is this because every equivalence class of $X^{\mathbb N} / \sim $ is uniquely defined by a row of constants $x, x, x, \dots$ for $x \in X$?

Comment: No, not every equivalence class is represented by a constant function. But that's not what we need. We only need to show that there are at least $|X|$ many equivalence classes. And for $x \neq y$ in $X$ we have that $c_x \not \sim c_y$ -- hence the method above yields $|X|$ many equivalence classes.